# Creating a custom button with circled text inside

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, view, drawable

[I'm trying to make a button like so.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBUG7.jpg)

Properties:
- Rounded
- Letter: like A, B, C, D, etc.
- Text: Any string, in the example the strings are the numbers.

I don't know from where to start. Currently here is what I have for my buttons:

File: button.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners android:radius="100dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <padding
        android:left="16dp"
        android:top="16dp"
        android:right="16dp"
        android:bottom="16dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically

For **ROUNDED** Options

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#000" />
<size
    android:width="40dp"
    android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

And use it in your activity as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <TextView
        android:background="@drawable/button_background_test"
        android:text="A"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In the same manner you can design your outer button as well.

Happy Coding!